# sending 401/403 error to client based on condition in service classs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

asp.net 5 Authoriation(default) in startup class.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                o.SaveToken = true;
              .....
            });
```

In ther service class i am sending error

```
var user =  await _userManager.Users.Include(u=>u.Roles).Include(u => u.Bank).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u=>u.UserName == request.UserName);
      

        var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, request.Password, lockoutOnFailure: true);

    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        throw new ApiException("User Locked out / Inform admin");
    }

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
       throw new ApiException("Invalid UserName or Password");   //What exception details to send?
    }
```

I have written exception hndler midlleware for ApiException like below

```
  public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                var response = context.Response;
                response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var responseModel = new Response<string>(error?.Message);

                switch (error)
                {
                    case ApiException e:
                        // custom application error
                        response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        break;

                 ....
                    default:
                        // unhandled error
                        response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        break;
                }
                var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(responseModel);

                await response.WriteAsync(result);
            }
        }
```

Now i need send custom error ( 401 & 403) in user service based on authorization failed cases..

How can i send 401 or 403 error to client in asp.net core (.net 5)..

please suggest

Comment: Use the [HttpResponse.StatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-5.0) property

Comment: Upon closer inspection of your code, you're already doing this by `(int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest`

Comment: Btw Security Best Practices say don't. Send a 404. Knowing the enpoint exists and just failed credentials is already a thing attackers can work with.

Comment: @Fildor thanks for suggestion. could you pls  sample code where i can i send 401 error?

Comment: @MindSwipe i need to send  401 or 403 error what is best practise for  do it in middlware or something else..

Comment: I personally like the approach of a middleware for common exceptions, like not being logged in, so I don't have to check it in every single API method

Comment: @MindSwipe do you have error handler of sample code how to handle 401/403 eror code in the answer ?